# Combining AJAX requests using $.when and sending the data to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, multiple-instances

I have functions and AJAX calls that update content in the page that need to be separate, however on page load they need to all load together hence my use of $.when - but my understanding of sending data between functions and using $.when is terrible - I've looked at several solutions to combine AJAX calls and all seem to fail for me. Here's my solution currently:

1. I have 2 functions that run seperate AJAX requests.
2. Then I call these from $.when
3. The data is returned and in correct JSON format (verified on JSONlint)
   However, when passed back through $.when the data is unset / lost somehow and at this point I dont understand whats happening. 
   I can output the data within the AJAX function, but if I attempt to output from within the $.when function, or within the onload_sendData function, the data always becomes "undefined".

I've tried JSON.stringify, and JSON.parse both before passing to a function and after - makes no difference, data always becomes undefined when I try to read it after passing to the next function this way. Perhaps I'm missing something fundamental on how Javascript passes data, hope someone can help.

```
function onload_Categories() {
    $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: '/index/categories',
              ContentType : 'application/json',
              success: function (data1) {
                return data1;
              },
              error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                return errortThrown;
              }
          })
}

function onload_Subscribed() {
    return $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: '/index/getsubscribed',
              ContentType : 'application/json',
              success: function (data2) {
                return data2;
              },
              error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                return errortThrown;
              }
          })
}

function onload_sendData(data1) {
  alert(data1); // "UNDEFINED"
  //processCategories(data1); // send data to populate the page categories
  //processSubscribed(data2); // send data to populate the subscription data
}

  (function($){
      $(window).load(function(){
```

v1

```
$.when(onload_Categories(),onload_Subscribed()).then(onload_sendData);
```

v2

```
$.when(onload_Categories(),onload_Subscribed()).then(function(data1,data2){


    alert(data1); // "UNDEFINED"
    alert(JSON.parse(data1); // "UNDEFINED"

    })

    })
 })
```

And here's a snippet of the json data retrieved from the category ajax function:

```
> [{"categorytitle":"accessories","category_id":"56","parent":"7","count":0,"p_count":0,"ad_ids":0,"rem_ads_age":0,"rem_ads_loc":0,"hassub":0},{"categorytitle":"accessories","category_id":"64","parent":"9","count":0,"p_count":0,"ad_ids":0,"rem_ads_age":0,"rem_ads_loc":0,"hassub":0},{"categorytitle":"accessories","category_id":"72","parent":"11","count":0,"p_count":0,"ad_ids":0,"rem_ads_age":0,"rem_ads_loc":0,"hassub":0},{"categorytitle":"activities","category_id":"57","parent":"7","count":0,"p_count":0,"ad_ids":0,"rem_ads_age":0,"rem_ads_loc":0,"hassub":0},{"categorytitle":"activities","category_id":"81","parent":"15","count":0,"p_count":0,"ad_ids":0,"rem_ads_age":0,"rem_ads_loc":0,"hassub":0},{"categorytitle":"appliances","category_id":"83","parent":"16","count":0,"p_count":0,"ad_ids":0,"rem_ads_age":0,"rem_ads_loc":0,"hassub":0},{"categorytitle":"apps","category_id":"4","parent":"0","count":2,"p_count":2,"ad_ids":"25,27,","rem_ads_age":0,"rem_ads_loc":0,"hassub":0},{"categorytitle":"auto","category_id":"18","parent":"0","count":1,"p_count":3,"ad_ids":"27,","rem_ads_age":0,"rem_ads_loc":0,"hassub":1},{"categorytitle":"bags","category_id":"32","parent":"1","count":0,"p_count":0,"ad_ids":0,"rem_ads_age":0,"rem_ads_loc":0,"hassub":0},{"categorytitle":"belts","category_id":"25","parent":"1","count":0,"p_count":0,"ad_ids":0,"rem_ads_age":0,"rem_ads_loc":0,"hassub":0},{"categorytitle":"body
> care","category_id":"3","parent":"0","count":0,"p_count":1,"ad_ids":0,"rem_ads_age":0,"rem_ads_loc":0,"hassub":1},{"categorytitle":"body
> work and
> \n\nrepair","category_id":"101","parent":"18","count":0,"p_count":0,"ad_ids":0,"rem_ads_age":0,"rem_ads_loc":0,"hassub":0},{"categorytitle":"books","category_id":"39","parent":"2","count":0,"p_count":0,"ad_ids":0,"rem_ads_age":0,"rem_ads_loc":0,"hassub":0},{"categorytitle":"business","category_id":"19","parent":"0","count":0,"p_count":0,"ad_ids":0,"rem_ads_age":0,"rem_ads_loc":0,"hassub":0},{"categorytitle":"Business
> insurance","category_id":"110","parent":"105","count":0,"p_count":0,"ad_ids":0,"rem_ads_age":0,"rem_ads_loc":0,"hassub":0},{"categorytitle":"cafes","category_id":"58","parent":"8","count":0,"p_count":0,"ad_ids":0,"rem_ads_age":0,"rem_ads_loc":0,"hassub":0},{"categorytitle":"cameras","category_id":"88","parent":"16","count":0,"p_count":0,"ad_ids":0,"rem_ads_age":0,"rem_ads_loc":0,"hassub":0},{"categorytitle":"car
> hire","category_id":"99","parent":"18","count":1,"p_count":1,"ad_ids":"20,","rem_ads_age":0,"rem_ads_loc":0,"hassub":0},{"categorytitle":"cars","category_id":"98","parent":"18","count":1,"p_count":1,"ad_ids":"20,","rem_ads_age":0,"rem_ads_loc":0,"hassub":0},{"categorytitle":"computers","category_id":"86","parent":"16","count":0,"p_count":0,"ad_ids":0,"rem_ads_age":0,"rem_ads_loc":0,"hassub":0},{"categorytitle":"computers
> and
> tablets","category_id":"90","parent":"16","count":0,"p_count":0,"ad_ids":0,"rem_ads_age":0,"rem_ads_loc":0,"hassub":0},{"categorytitle":"consoles
> and
> \n\ngames","category_id":"89","parent":"16","count":0,"p_count":0,"ad_ids":0,"rem_ads_age":0,"rem_ads_loc":0,"hassub":0},{"categorytitle":"cruises","category_id":"63","parent":"9","count":0,"p_count":0,"ad_ids":0,"rem_ads_age":0,"rem_ads_loc":0,"hassub":0},{"categorytitle":"cufflinks","category_id":"27","parent":"1","count":0,"p_count":0,"ad_ids":0,"rem_ads_age":0,"rem_ads_loc":0,"hassub":0}]
```

And just to be thorough, and for your understanding - the below IS working in passing data between functions:

```
function getCategories($c) {

  $.when(

      $.get('/index/categories')

  ).then(function(categories) {

    processCategories(categories, $c);

  });

}

function processCategories(categories, $c) {

var jsonData = JSON.parse(categories); // data OK

etc...
```

Comment: You need to return the promise from your functions: `return $.ajax(...)`

Comment: You might have to speak in lamens terms, I'm a complete novice... I tried this but still no luck $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: '/index/categories',
              ContentType : 'application/json',
              success: function (data1) {
                return $.ajax(data1);

Comment: you've led me in the right direction I think I've found out what you mean, thanks barm!

Comment: It appears $when is also combing my data response which is a problem

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might be curious - the AJAX needs to be specically returnd like so:

```
return $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: '/index/getsubscribed',
              ContentType : 'application/json',
})
```

and using this data you need to reference the first index as the AJAX response is an array.

```
        $.when(
          onload_Categories(),
          onload_Subscribed()
          ).then(function(data1,data2) {
            var categories = data1[0]; 

// 0 - is your data, 1 - AJAX fail/success response, 2 - other ajax response object data.
              processCategories(categories);
            var subscribed = data2[0];
              processSubscribed(subscribed);

          })
```

Probably basic stuff but lost me a few hours of my life as I'm fairly new to this, hope it helps someone.

UPDATE:

My server wouldn't accept 2 GETS in the single $.when statement - the 2nd would always receive a 500 internal server error- no body I've seen has stacked the $.when statement, but this seems like it's the only solution and works well for me...

```
$.when(
          onload_Categories()
          ).then(function(data) {
            var categories = data;
            alert(categories);
              processCategories(categories);
              $.when(
                onload_Subscribed()
                ).then(function(data) {
                  var subscribed = data;
                  alert(subscribed);
                    processSubscribed(subscribed);
                })
          })
```